# How to filter values in Editable ComboBox or ComboViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, eclipse-plugin, swt-awt

how to filter the Values of Combo in SWT.

For Examble if i have a,abc,bcd,acd,com,aaa,bed,bot,catvalues in combo dropdown.

if i type "a" in combo it should display only "a,abc,acd,aaa" in combo dropdown.

is there any way to get?

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want to do you might be better off using a Text field with auto completion (AutoCompleteField).

Answer (score 1):

JFace ComboViewer api allows the setting of a filter (ViewerFilter). If you are using JFace, this should help.